# How to provide an Implementation in c++?

Tags: c++, class, implementation

> The following problems appeared on Exam 2 in previous years.
>
> ```
> class SchoolBus
> {
> public:
>     SchoolBus(int seats, int seatedStudents);
>     bool addStudents(int students);
>     bool removeStudents(int students);
>     int getStudents() const;
>
> private:
>     int seats;
>     int seatedStudents;
> };
> ```
>
> 2) Provide an implementation of the SchoolBus constructor.
>
> ```
> SchoolBus(int seats, int seatedStudents) {
>    this->seats = seats;
>    this->seatedStudents = seatedStudents;
> }
> ```

I do not get #2. I get how that's the answer but how would you write that in code and compile it? I want to actually compile it and see how it works.

Comment: Did you try compiling the code?

Answer (score 3):

In #2 the code is called a *constructor*, so I'll write the constructor in terms I'm more familiar with:

```
SchoolBus::SchoolBus(int seating_capacity, int students_in_bus)
: seats(seating_capacity),
  seatedStudents(students_in_bus)
{
}
```

To code it, I'd probably put it in a file called "school_bus.cpp":

```
#include "school_bus.hpp"

SchoolBus::SchoolBus(int seating_capacity, int students_in_bus)
: seats(seating_capacity),
  seatedStudents(students_in_bus)
{
}
```

I would place the class declaration in a header file, called "school_bus.hpp":

```
class SchoolBus
{
public:
    SchoolBus(int seats, int seatedStudents);
    bool addStudents(int students);
    bool removeStudents(int students);
    int getStudents() const;

private:
    int seats;
    int seatedStudents;
};
```

To compile, I'd probably use `g++`:

```
  g++ -g -o school_bus.o -c school_bus.cpp
```

To test it, I'd create a 'main` function:

```
#include "school_bus.hpp"
int main(void)
{
  static SchoolBus yellow_bus(25, 36);
  return 0;
}
```

This may require building and linking:

```
g++ -g -o school_bus.exe main.cpp school_bus.o
```

Then I could use the debugger:

```
gdb ./school_bus.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor implementation is not properly qualified. It should be prefixed with the class name.

**This:**

```
SchoolBus(int seats, int seatedStudents) {
   this->seats = seats;
   this->seatedStudents = seatedStudents;
}
```

**Should become:**

```
SchoolBus::SchoolBus(int seats, int seatedStudents) {
   this->seats = seats;
   this->seatedStudents = seatedStudents;
}
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Either put it fully with the declaration like so:

```
class SchoolBus
{
public:
    SchoolBus(int seats, int seatedStudents)
    {
        this->seats = seats;
        this->seatedStudents = seatedStudents;
    }
    bool addStudents(int students);
    bool removeStudents(int students);
    int getStudents() const;

private:
    int seats;
    int seatedStudents;
};
```

or seperate the two

```
//in schoolbus.h
#pragma once
class SchoolBus
{
public:
    SchoolBus(int seats, int seatedStudents);
    bool addStudents(int students);
    bool removeStudents(int students);
    int getStudents() const;

private:
    int seats;
    int seatedStudents;
};

//in schoolbus.cpp
#include "schoolbus.h"

SchoolBus::SchoolBus(int seats, int seatedStudents) {
   this->seats = seats;
   this->seatedStudents = seatedStudents;
}
```

It's also worth noting that usually this would be done in the initializer list like so:

```
SchoolBus::SchoolBus(int pSeats, int pSeatedStudents) :
  seats(pSeats),
  seatedStudents(pSeatedStudents)
{
}
```